# X axis not displaying on bar chart using d3.js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I have implemented dynamic Grouped bar chart using d3.js. Its working fine.According to my data,Y axis is displaying TotalOrders. I want to display Months on x axis.But its not getting display.Here is my code:

```
    function Groupchart() {
    debugger;
    var w = 500;
    var h = 600;
    var MARGINS = { top: 1, right: 20, bottom: 2, left: 50 }
    var colors = [["TotalTicket", "#377EB8"],
                  ["TotalOrders", "#4DAF4A"]];
    var dataset = [{ "Month": "Jan", "TotalOrders": 7324, "TotalTicket": 23954, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "10%" },
                   { "Month": "Feb", "TotalOrders": 3738, "TotalTicket": 12319, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "12%" },
                   { "Month": "March", "TotalOrders": 4466, "TotalTicket": 15524, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "14%" },
                   { "Month": "May", "TotalOrders": 100, "TotalTicket": 200, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "50%" },
                   { "Month": "Oct", "TotalOrders": 109, "TotalTicket": 2000, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "9%" }]

    var x0Scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                       .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                       .rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, w - MARGINS.right], 0.1);
    var x1Scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d.TotalOrders; })])
                    .rangeRoundBands([MARGINS.left, w - MARGINS.right], 0.1);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return (d.TotalTicket + 10000); })])
                    .range([h - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]);
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x0Scale).tickSize(5).tickSubdivide(true).orient("bottom");
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).tickSize(5).orient("left").tickSubdivide(true);

    var TotalOrders = function (d) {
        return d.TotalOrders;
    };

    var TotalTicket = function (d) {
        return d.TotalTicket;
    };
    var Month = function (d) {
        return d.Month;
    };

    var Average = function (d) {
        return d.Avg;
    };

    var commaFormat = d3.format(',');

    //SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("#searchVolume")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
                .attr("margin", MARGINS);


    /*Draw X Axis values*/
    svg.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - MARGINS.bottom) + ')')
      .call(xAxis);

    /*Draw Y Axis values*/
    svg.append('svg:g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (MARGINS.left) + ',0)')
      .call(yAxis);

    // Graph Bars
    var sets = svg.selectAll(".set")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "set")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            return "translate(" + x0Scale(i) + ",0)"
        })

        .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
            //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
            var xPosition = parseFloat(x0Scale(i) + x0Scale.rangeBand() / 6);
            var yPosition = 0;
            //Update Tooltip Position & value
            d3.select("#tooltip")
                .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                .select("#cpcVal")
                .text(d.Month);
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            //Remove the tooltip
            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
        });

    sets.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "TotalTicket")
        .attr("width", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return yScale(d.TotalTicket);
        })
        .attr("x", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return h - yScale(d.TotalTicket);
        })
        .attr("fill", colors[0][1])
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300 })
        .duration(1000)

    sets.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "TotalOrders")
        .attr("width", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return yScale(d.TotalOrders);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return h - yScale(d.TotalOrders);
        })
       .attr("fill", colors[1][1])


    var legend = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "legend")
     //.attr("x", w - 65)
     //.attr("y", 50)
     .attr("height", 100)
     .attr("width", 100)
     .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)');

    var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(colors);

    legendRect.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", w - 65)
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10);

    legendRect
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return d[1];
        });

    var legendText = legend.selectAll('text').data(colors);

    legendText.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", w - 52);

    legendText
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            return i * 20 + 9;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d[0];
        });

    svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset, Average)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .text(function (d) {
           return(d.Avg);
       })
       .attr("class", "bartext")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("x", function (d, i) {
       return x0Scale(i) + x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2;
       })
       .attr("y", function (d) {
           return  yScale(d.TotalTicket) - 10;
       })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("fill", "black");
}
```

Can anybody please me what is the actual problem?

Comment: can you post this code in jsfiddle

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the original problem shown: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/mvfmpdpp/. I think this is just a problem with margins, try following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304). The `xAxis` is being drawn but is hidden because the bottom margin isn't used correctly. Also I don't think that `svg` has a `margin` attribute?

Comment: try this fiddle, months not assigned to `x0Scale`

http://jsfiddle.net/e1450pqh/3/

Comment: in this fiddle you can see number in x axis . is this fine or you need months in x axis??

Comment: Your Fiddle  seems to be empty-@  Manjunath Siddappa.Here is the fiddle for my code:http: //jsfiddle.net/henbox/mvfmpdpp/

Comment: Yes..I was looking for Months in x axis.@ Manjunath Siddappa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a margin issue. Your effective height is `height - margin.top - margin.bottom`. I've fixed the example accordingly (with readability improvement).

To use months in ordinal scale you must initialize the scale with, yeah, months. Then use the scale to map an ordinal value to a x-scale value, e.g. `x0Scale(d.Month)`.

```js
function createGroupchart() 
{
  var width  = 500;
  var height = 180;
  var margin = {
    'top'    : 5, 
    'right'  : 20, 
    'bottom' : 20, 
    'left'   : 50 
  };
  var colors = [
    ["TotalTicket", "#377EB8"],
    ["TotalOrders", "#4DAF4A"]
  ];
  var dataset = [
    {"Month": "Jan",   "TotalOrders": 7324, "TotalTicket": 23954, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "10%"},
    {"Month": "Feb",   "TotalOrders": 3738, "TotalTicket": 12319, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "12%"},
    {"Month": "March", "TotalOrders": 4466, "TotalTicket": 15524, "Year": "2013", "Avg": "14%"},
    {"Month": "May",   "TotalOrders": 100,  "TotalTicket": 200,   "Year": "2013", "Avg": "50%"},
    {"Month": "Oct",   "TotalOrders": 109,  "TotalTicket": 2000,  "Year": "2013", "Avg": "9%" }
  ];

  var x0Scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dataset.map(function(d)
    {
      return d.Month;
    }))
    .rangeRoundBands([margin.left, width - margin.right], 0.1);

  var x1Scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) 
    { 
      return d.TotalOrders; 
    })])
    .rangeRoundBands([margin.left, width - margin.right], 0.1);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) 
    { 
      return (d.TotalTicket + 10000); 
    })])
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0Scale)
    .tickSize(5)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickSize(5)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSubdivide(true);

  var commaFormat = d3.format(',');


  // SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",  width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("margin", margin);

  // Draw X Axis values
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (height - margin.bottom - margin.top) + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

  // Draw Y Axis values
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',0)')
    .call(yAxis);

  // Graph Bars
  var sets = svg.selectAll(".set")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "set")
    .attr("transform", function(d) 
    {
      return "translate(" + x0Scale(d.Month) + ",0)"
    });

  sets.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "TotalTicket")
    .attr("width", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) 
    {
      return yScale(d.TotalTicket);
    })
    .attr("x", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("height", function(d) 
    {
      return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.TotalTicket);
    })
    .attr("fill", colors[0][1]);

  sets.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "TotalOrders")
    .attr("width", x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2)
    .attr("y", function(d) 
    {
      return yScale(d.TotalOrders);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) 
    {
      return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.TotalOrders);
    })
    .attr("fill", colors[1][1])


  var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-30,20)');

  var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(colors);

  legendRect.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 65)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10);

  legendRect
    .attr("y", function(d, i) 
    {
      return i * 20;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) 
    {
      return d[1];
    });

  var legendText = legend.selectAll('text').data(colors);

  legendText.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 52);

  legendText
    .attr("y", function(d, i) 
    {
      return i * 20 + 9;
    })
    .text(function(d) 
    {
      return d[0];
    });

  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset, function(d)
    {
      return d.Avg;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) 
    {
      return d.Avg;
    })
    .attr("class", "bartext")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) 
    {
      return x0Scale(d.Month) + x0Scale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) 
    {
      return  yScale(d.TotalTicket) - 10;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "15px")
    .attr("fill", "black");
}
createGroupchart()
```

```css
svg .axis path, .axis line {
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : #000;
  shape-rendering : crispEdges;
}

svg .x.axis path {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```

Comment: @ saaj it is not margin issue, what she is asking- months instead of numbers in x axis

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa Oh, I must have misinterpreted it as it wasn't way to clear. And the margins were also an issue ;-) I've edited the answer, that's for heads up.